# Selecting rows based on range of vector values in Pandas

Tags: numpy, pandas

I'm trying to split data into training, validation, and test using numpy and pandas.

I know this works (it's from the `sklearn` Iris example):

```
DataFrame['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(train)) <= .75
train, test = DataFrame[DataFrame['is_train']==True], DataFrame[DataFrame['is_train']==False]
```

But how do I do something similar for a range of values, eg, .33 < x < .66?

This does not work:

```
DataFrame['segment'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(df))
DataFrame[DataFrame['segment'] < .33 & DataFrame['segment'] < .66]
```

Finally, if you're aware of a better way, pray tell.

To the best of my knowledge, `sklearn`'s `cross_validation.train_test_split()` doesn't do three-way splits.

Comment: little mistake:
DataFrame[DataFrame['segment'] > .33 & DataFrame['segment'] < .66]
For the answer, Edchum's is clear and concise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the conditions in parentheses:

```
DataFrame[(DataFrame['segment'] < .33) & (DataFrame['segment'] < .66)]
```

The `&` operator has higher precedence than `<`: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Also typically one splits the data into various splits according to whatever criteria you desire: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation and you iterate over the various splits to test the robustness of your model. It's not that useful IMO to have a fixed validation set as how do you know how representative that validation set is?

Comment: Thanks. Would you happen to know whether a three-way split can be done with cross_validation.train_test_split() ?

Comment: Why do you need a validation set? Wouldn't be better to generate the train test splits and average the perf over those splits?

Comment: Possibly. It's an exercise I'm working through. And I'd like to know the best practice for this.